# BST breadth-first-traversal including deleted nodes

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

Given this tree:

```
         7
    5         9
  _  6      8  _ 
    _ _    _ _
```

I want the output to be:

```
[[Node(7)], [Node(5), Node(9)], [None, Node(6), Node(8), None], [None, None, None, None]]
```

So it is important that 'None' is included and that the output is lists in a list.

I tried a lot of things but this is where I am right now:

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, key, value=None):
    self.key = key
    self.value = value
    self.parent = None
    self.left_child = None
    self.right_child = None
    self.height = 0 

def breadth_first_traversal(self):
  self.height = 1
  to_do = [self.root]
  if (self.root == None):
    return to_do
  output = []
  current_height = self.height
  output.append([str(node) for node in to_do])

  while (to_do):
    done = []
    current = to_do.pop(0)
    if (current.height > current_height):
      current_height += 1
    if (current.left_child):
      current.left_child.height = current_height + 1 
      to_do.append(current.left_child)
      done.append(current.left_child)
    elif (not current.left_child):
      done.append(None)
    if (current.right_child):
      current.right_child.height = current_height + 1 
      to_do.append(current.right_child)
      done.append(current.right_child)
    elif (not current.right_child):
      done.append(None) 
    output.append([str(node) for node in done])

  print(output)
  return output
```

The output right now is:

```
[['7'], ['5', '9'], ['None', '6'], ['8', 'None'], ['None', 'None'], ['None', 'None']]
```

I understand why it is making lists of 2 elements, because that's what I'm saying it should do right now. I just don't know how to take into account the levels.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a binary search tree, it makes sense that the results are being concatenated to the array as tuples.

If you want to concatenate the arrays based on their relative depth, then you would need to implement an aggregator function that continues to append elements to a list until the depth is incremented, at which point the list is saved and cleared for the next set.

Alternatively, you could pass the result you have to a helper function that simply concatenates the elements the way you want.

**Edit 1:** The following should work; however, I have not tested it. I simply moved `done` outside of the `while` loop, so that it does not get re-initialized after each iteration. Furthermore, I only append `done` to `output` when the depth is incremented, because this is the moment when there are no other elements to process.

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, key, value=None):
    self.key = key
    self.value = value
    self.parent = None
    self.left_child = None
    self.right_child = None
    self.height = 0 

def breadth_first_traversal(self):
  self.height = 1
  to_do = [self.root]
  if (self.root == None):
    return to_do
  output = []
  current_height = self.height
  output.append([str(node) for node in to_do])
  done = []

  while (to_do):
    current = to_do.pop(0)
    if (current.height > current_height):
      current_height += 1
      output.append([str(node) for node in done])
      done = []
    if (current.left_child):
      current.left_child.height = current_height + 1 
      to_do.append(current.left_child)
      done.append(current.left_child)
    elif (not current.left_child):
      done.append(None)
    if (current.right_child):
      current.right_child.height = current_height + 1 
      to_do.append(current.right_child)
      done.append(current.right_child)
    elif (not current.right_child):
      done.append(None) 

  print(output)
  return output
```

Comment: I feel like I am doing that right now with the 'done' list, but I don't know how I would use the height correctly

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to find all nodes, including the leaves storing `None`, along with the depths of each node, and then grouping by the depths:

For simplicity, I have created a binary tree that can be easily initialized using `kwargs`, along with the method to traverse the tree and provide the running depth values:

```
from itertools import groupby

class Node:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i, None) for i in ['left', 'right', 'value']}
  def get_depths(self, _count = 0):
    yield [_count, self.value]
    if self.left is not None:
      yield from self.left.get_depths(_count+1)
    else:
      yield [_count+1, None]
    if self.right is not None:
      yield from self.right.get_depths(_count+1)
    else:
      yield [_count+1, None]

tree = Node(value=7, left=Node(value=5, right=Node(value=6)), right=Node(value=9, left=Node(value=8)))
flattened = [[c for _, c in b] for _, b in groupby(sorted(list(tree.get_depths()), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[[7], [5, 9], [None, 6, 8, None], [None, None, None, None]]
```